# Replacing RAISERROR with THROW

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In my procedures historically, I've always caught an exception, then raised it after a `ROLLBACK`.  I see in MSDN that the recommended approach (for SQL2012+) is to `THROW`.

Based on this example procedure:

```
CREATE PROC my_procName

    @id int

AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

            UPDATE [tbl_A] WHERE (ID=@id);
            UPDATE [tbl_B] WHERE (fkID=@id);
            UPDATE [tbl_C] WHERE (fkID=@id);

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000)
        DECLARE @ErrSeverity int
        SET @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
    END CATCH
GO
```

Is this the correct way to throw the exception, while preserving the `ROLLBACK`?

```
CREATE PROC my_procName

    @id int

AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

            UPDATE [tbl_A] WHERE (ID=@id);
            UPDATE [tbl_B] WHERE (fkID=@id);
            UPDATE [tbl_C] WHERE (fkID=@id);

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        THROW
    END CATCH
GO
```

I have already looked at MSDN, Google, and this site for examples, but none include the `ROLLBACK`, so this is just a quick question to make absolutely sure.

Comment: Looks ok to me - rollback the transaction in the catch then throw the error, that's how it would look in .NET

Comment: For maintenance safety I always like to add a @@trancount and XACT_STATE check before rolling back but otherwise yes this is a great way to do this.

Comment: I know this is old but `ROLLBACK TRAN` errors if the transaction is not committable "    -- XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and  
    --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  
"  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record statement before THROW statement should be terminated by semicolon. But generally your approach is correct - THROW ends the batch therefore must be the last statement you want to execute in your catch block. Optionally you can use THROW with parameters:
`THROW [ { error_number | @local_variable },
        { message | @local_variable },
        { state | @local_variable } ] 
[ ; ]`